# Hibernate 4.1.9 : Which jar files do I need?

Tags: java, hibernate

I started to learn Hibernate framework from "[Hibernate 3.2 in Simple Steps](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hibernate-Simple-Steps-John-Wilfred/dp/8177228897)" book, but I downloaded latest version of Hibernate which is 4.1.9. According to the book there are many essential jars we need to add to the class path like

- Anttr-2.7.6.jar
- asm.jar
- asm-attrs.jar
- cglib-2.1.3.jar
- commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- .
  .
  . etc.

But I can't find all those required jars in new version. So what can I do without going for an old version ?? Do I just only need to add jars in required folder,,, can any one please tell me what jars I should need to add class path (4.1.9 version).
This question may be silly but I'm a beginner and I'm stuck here. Please help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

The zip file which you download will have a required folder inside lib.It will be having all the necessary jars.

Comment: we  need slf4j.jar as the primary one

Comment: Why do we need `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`? we already have its implementation as `hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar`

Answer (score 5):

This is well explained in [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/ch01.html#hibernate-gsg-setup-releaseBundle) (never just depend on a book when there's an abundance of good online material available, as is the case with Hibernate):

> The lib/required/ directory contains all the JARs Hibernate requires.
>   All the jars in this directory must also be included in your project's
>   classpath.

All jars you need are right there, in the .zip file you already downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are downloaded Hibernate Software( **http://hibernate.org/** ) following location.

```
Hibernate_HOME = /home/rangareddy/Hibernate/hibernate-release-4.2.7.Final
```

Jar files:

```
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/antlr-2.7.7.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/jpa/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest learn to use **maven** or **gradle** first and let them to help you set up the dependencies.

Using a dependency management tools in such days of java development is important and useful, all well known java libraries support this way and also it is recommanded.

A tech book may be outdated very soon, for such of this kind of details, the official doc would be always the first choice.

Answer (score -1):

in case of using maven add this code to your pom file

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```