# Libraries in hibernate 4.x

Tags: hibernate, orm

I am studing a book about Hibernate. The book is about Hibernate 3 but I would like to use hibernate 4.x.

There are some libraries in Hibernate 3 that I can't find in Hibernate 4 (for example `antlr.jar`)

I'd like to read about the changes between these versions of Hibernate. Does anyone know where can I find the changelog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all required libraries are in `lib/required` in the zip bundle of Hibernate. Take a look at [Hibernate 4.1.9 : Which jar files do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13978020/851811).

[image: Screenshot showing the libraries inside the Hibernate bundle]

If you're using Maven, all dependencies should be downloaded and handled automatically.

As for Hibernate 4's changelog, here's the answer [What's new in Hibernate 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6830501/851811).

Answer (score 0):

you can find all change logs from changlog.txt within hibernate-distribution,

or the [hibernate developer's blog](http://in.relation.to/tag/Hibernate)