# Which jar files should i include in my first hibernate project?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I just started developing my first hibernate project but i need some jar files for my first hibernate project. Which jar files am i to use?

Comment: If you want hibernate jar file you should download it from hibernate site else mention which jar files?

Comment: You should be using Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies for you. You'll probably be wanting `hibernate-entitymanager` and dependencies; maybe a few others depending on features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the required jar for Hibernate 4.1.9.it's same as [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978020/hibernate-4-1-9-which-jar-files-do-i-need)

```
1).antlr-2.7.7.jar
2).commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
3).dom4j-1.6.1.jar
4).javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
5).hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
6).hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
7).hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
8).jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
9).jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

Comment: thank you for your precious time for helping me .. i added this to my project

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you can download the .jar file and include it in your project library:

http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

Also, you should consider using Maven. That way, you may retrieve the dependency using pom.xml

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate

You can read about Maven here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven

Answer (score 0):

For successfully running the hibernate application, you should have the hibernate4.jar file.

[download the latest hibernate jar file](http://www.hibernate.org/downloads). Some other jar files or packages are required such as

- cglib
- log4j
- commons
- SLF4J
- dom4j
- xalan
- xerces

[download the required jar files](http://www.javatpoint.com/src/hb/hibernatejar.zip) for hibernate